# How can i clear the bitmap in android?

Tags: android, email, bitmap, screenshot

Hi i have an application to take the screenshot and  send to the email. When i took the screenshot second time and attach to the email, the email contains the first screenshot. I think the bitmap is not clearing. Can any one please help me for that. I am sorry for my poor english.

This is my code;

```
email_icon1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "email_icon clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                     View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
                        // View v1 = iv.getRootView(); //even this works
                        // View v1 = findViewById(android.R.id.content); //this works too
                        // but gives only content
                     v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                        myBitmap = v1.getDrawingCache();

                        saveBitmap(myBitmap);
                }
            });

public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
          String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                  + File.separator + "Pictures/screenshot.png";
          File imagePath = new File(filePath);
          FileOutputStream fos;
          try {
              fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
              bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
              fos.flush();
              fos.close();
              sendMail(filePath);
          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
              Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
          } catch (IOException e) {
              Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
          }
        }

        public void sendMail(String path) {


          Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
          emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                  new String[] { "athulya@extraslice.com" });
          emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                  "giMobile ScreenShot");
          emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                  "Sent from my AndroidTab");
          emailIntent.setType("image/png");
          Uri myUri = Uri.parse("file://" + path);
          emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, myUri);
          startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
        }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Clear bitmap data using following code.. bitmap.recycle(), bitmap = null

Comment: I tried, but it causing null pointer exception.

Comment: Once bitmap is saved in a file. u'r clearing right ?. Can you update your code with bitmap recyle?

Answer (score 0):

in order for you to recreate the bitmap from the view please follow this order

```
    holder.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bmp = holder.getDrawingCache();
```

then after saving make sure you `destroy` the `view Caches` and add this to the end of your save method to completely destroy the view cache and  to re-start again re-drawing the view each time you click the save method or whatever method you are using..

```
holder.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

After getting bitmap do this

> v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);  myBitmap = v1.getDrawingCache();
>   v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);  saveBitmap(myBitmap);